# React Table: column resizing NOT real-time?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

We've being trying react-table in our project to display complex tables. (customer info, projects, .etc)

For simple table like the [official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/column-resizing), the resizing feels smooth and worked perfect.

But we want to display complex contents (avatars, hovering and popups), and the resizing becomes very heavy and lagging.

I like the google spreadsheet resizing, with which the real resizing doesn't happen until the mouse is released.

Is there a way to implement this using react-table?

Or should I consider an alternative?

Comment: Hey Junming, for reducing the lag, I will suggest to use virtualization this will improve the performance significantly.